# Does "Holy Cause" only work if my equipped Weapon deals Holy Damage?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-crusader

I am talking about this passive skill:

[image: screenshot of skill in question]

Judging from the description, it should increase my weapon damage by 10%, no matter which weapon I wield. The heal should only happen if my weapon has a holy damage modifier, but should still proc when I use skills that deal holy. However, in this [discussion](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12329673159#4) on the battle.net forums, people claim it only works at all if you have holy damage on your weapon.

Can someone clarify this please?

Comment: PC Masterrace, not console, just fyi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*+10% Weapon Damage*

To address the damage first, the +10% weapon damage modification from the passive skill only affects weapon damage itself. For example, given this weapon

[image]

Its weapon damage is 1262-1634. The modification will increase that 10%, making it 1388-1797, which is significant. As stated in the passive tooltip, this applies to *all* weapons. Essentially it is the same as having the "+10% damage" primary stat.

*Heal up to 1%*

The healing is a slightly different case. It does work for any holy skill used. However, it is subject to "proc coefficients" which are blizzards way of silently screwing over many skills. Essentially, the 1% of total life healed is never the full 1%, and this can be seen by carefully reading the "**up to 1%**" part of the text.

First, if the holy damage hits more than 1 target at once, and it hit 10 targets, then each target can only yield 0.1% of the life healed max. After that, each target calculates a coefficient to multiply the life healed by. I am not sure what it is exactly for this skill, however, it is always less than 1 (again as indicated by the up to 1% part) so this means that it could very well be half of that sometimes.

In other words, if you have 100,000 life total, and hit one monster with holy damage, it is possible that you only heal 0.5% from that hit - or 500 life - which isn't much and could go unnoticed.

Comment: http://www.d3maxstats.com/procrates/ (Usually kept relatively up to date)

Comment: @pfayze - I had checked that site prior to this answer, but it does not list the proc rate for Holy Cause unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Originally in 2.0 this was the case - Holy Cause only worked if your weapon did holy damage. However, as of [patch 2.0.5](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/patch-notes/2-0-5), Holy Cause now works with all weapon types:

> Holy Cause
>   Damage bonus now applies to all weapons, not just Holy weapons

(taken from the Crusader section of the patch notes)

The date of the forum post you linked is from just after Reaper of Souls launched, and most likely before patch 2.0.5 was released.